# Hosting and displaying Html code

Tags: html

Would it be possible to host some Html code (just a simple image with link etc) on a website Eg [Arsenal News](http://www.footballnewsdaily.net/arsenal) and then for you to somehow implement this Html on various websites using the url and whenever you change the code on the url it will automatically change on the websites it's implemented on

Comment: Sounds like `<iframe>`

Comment: @RolandStarke Well, an iframe won't update itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you mean: External links.
You can of course have a site, where links point to external resources hosted anywhere.

Comment: No, I don't think you understand correctly. He seems to want to embed HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the location of the hosted page being linked to (www.example.com/code.html) does not change then the links will serve up the most current contents of that hosted page (barring a few caching scenarios), regardless of how many edits are made to the HTML contents of the code.html file itself.

If you're looking to embedded an external page's content into your page, then you'd be best to learn more about the `<iframe>` tag. Try http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp as a starting point.